# Java: Exception while connecting to Hbase 0.94.1

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have written a very short program to connect to `Hbase`.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
public class HbaseMonitor {
        public static void main(String args[]){
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                try{
                        HBaseAdmin hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
                        ClusterStatus clusterStatus = hbaseAdmin.getClusterStatus();
                        System.out.println("Has regions: "+clusterStatus.getRegionsCount());
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Compiled it using the same jars available in the `lib` directory of hbase as shown below:

```
javac -cp /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.1-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.3-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:. HbaseMonitor.java
```

And when I run it, I get below exceptions:

```
15/03/19 17:47:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
15/03/19 17:47:07 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 17277@ostrich-node1
15/03/19 17:47:07 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
15/03/19 17:47:07 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
15/03/19 17:47:07 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x4c31791de7041e, negotiated timeout = 180000
15/03/19 17:47:07 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1006
java.io.IOException: Call to ostrich-node1/192.168.151.50:60000 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.wrapException(HBaseClient.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:1079)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:150)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:141)
    at HbaseMonitor.main(HbaseMonitor.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.receiveResponse(HBaseClient.java:605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.run(HBaseClient.java:538)
```

Telnet to the hbase-master works fine:

```
[root@ostrich-node1 test]# telnet ostrich-node1 60000
Trying 192.168.151.50...
Connected to ostrich-node1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Telnet of localhost clearly shows that the client could connect to the hbase:

```
[root@ostrich-node1 test]# telnet localhost 2181
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Log of master (`hbase-hbase-master-ostrich-node1.log`) displays below warning for the above exception:

```
2015-03-19 17:47:07,711 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureServer: Incorrect header or version mismatch from 192.168.151.50:57502 got version 3 expected version 4
```

From the above warning, one may say that the `hadoop-core.jar` I am using for `hbase` is different from the one being used for `hadoop`. Yes, it was. So, I replaced the jar but unfortunately the error didn't go away.

Please note that I have executed my program on the same machine which has hbase installed.

Hbase version:

```
[root@ostrich-node1 logs]# hbase version 
15/03/19 17:59:17 INFO util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.94.1-Intel
```

Hadoop version:

```
[root@ostrich-node1 logs]# hadoop version
Hadoop 1.0.3-Intel
```

Hbase shell works:

```
[root@ostrich-node1 logs]# hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.1-Intel, r17177, Wed Sep 18 14:52:53 CST 2013

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ATTR                                                                                                                                                                                                       
RECO                                                                                                                                                                                                       
SUBSCRIBER                                                                                                                                                                                                 
SUBSCRIBER2                                                                                                                                                                                                
TPETEST                                                                                                                                                                                                    
test                                                                                                                                                                                                       
6 row(s) in 1.0700 seconds
```

So, what can be the issue?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me by doing following things:

1. Add path of the `HBASE_CONF` in the **end** of the `classpath`, like shown below (right click over image and open it in a new tab, if they are too small to understand):

[image]

**Note**: in my hbase master node, HBASE_CONF=/usr/lib/hbase/conf .

2. Unfortunately, but true, used depreacted method in the slightly modified program:

[image]

Note: `HBaseConfiguration()` is deprecated but works for hbase-0.94.1 (Intel).

And the output is shown below:

[image]

> Sorry, code highlighter was not working for large codes. Therefore, I
>   used images to show them properly.